# Improper integral $\int_0^1\frac{\log{(1-x^2)}}{(a-x)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

It seems that integral converges for $a>1$, but I have problem with singular point $1$. What happens in case $0<a\leq 1$? Also, is it possible to calculate this integral (I tried with partial integration, $u=\log(1-x^2)$, $v=-\frac{1}{x-a}$, but got divergent result).
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in(0,1)$ you have a non-integrable singularity (of the $1/x^2$ kind) inside the integration range, hence the integral does not exist. On the other hand, if $a>1$ we have

$$ I(a)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)+\log(1-x)}{(a-x)^2}\,dx \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{a-x}-\frac{1}{a-1}\right)\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\,dx,$$
and by partial fraction decomposition
$$I(a) = \frac{-2}{a^2-1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{a}{a-x}-\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\,dx = \frac{2}{a^2-1}\left(\log(2)+a\log\left(1-\frac{1}{a}\right)\right).$$

Equality holds for $a<0$, too. In the limit cases $a=0$ and $a=1$ we have

$$ I(0) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{x^2}\,dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{n}\,dx = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(2n-1)}= -2\log(2),$$

$$\begin{eqnarray*} I(1) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{(1-x)^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)+\log(2-x)}{x^2}\,dx = -\infty.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: What you took for u and v in partial integration?

Comment: @alans: I took $\frac{1}{a-x}-\frac{1}{a-1}$ as a primitive for $\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}$ and differentiated $\log(1-x^2)$.

Comment: Is this some kind of trick? I've never seen this before, I used $\frac{1}{a-x}$ as primitive and got sth that diverges...

Comment: @alans: picking a primitive that vanishes at an endpoint is an useful trick, for instance in proving that $\int_{0}^{r}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ is positive for any $r>0$.

Comment: $I(a)$ is clearly convergent for any $a>1$. It is negative, increasing and behaves like $(\ln 4-2)/a^2$ for large values of $a$.